# Does the request Node module limit outbound requests?

Tags: node.js, express, tcp, request

Running into an issue when load testing a server page, where we are making outbound requests to an api using the request module, and then on completion or error, redirecting the page (using express). Under stress the page we are posting to times out, and I'm wondering if it has to do with the max maxSockets parameter in that module. Does anyone know the default maxSockets for the request module? how to I change this to something reasonable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max sockets for the HTTP agent is defaulted to `5` per host.  Just set it to whatever amount is useful to you, maybe 1,000.

It's documented here:  https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets